# Poner en negrita una palabra en un texto estático en ireport (jasper)

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasper

Hola estoy intentando hacer un reporte con ireport en jasper y no estoy encontrando forma de poner solo una o varias palabras negrita dentro de un texto estatico, me da igual que sea estático o un text field, solo quiero poner en negrita una cosa dentro de un texto. Gracias por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado lo que hay que hacer es decirle que use el enmarcado de html:

```
            <reportElement x="155" y="41" width="50" height="40" uuid="895c759d-eb17-416c-af76-16af8bbe251e"/>
            <textElement markup="html"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<b>Negrita</b> texto"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funcionó con un TextField, poner el Markup en Styled y poner como contenido de campo:

```
"<style isBold='true' pdfFontName='Helvetica-Bold'>Ingrese cualquier texto " + $F{unCampoDeTexto} + " Otro Texto</style>"
```